# In IntelliJ Scala plugin, can I use scala-compiler.jar retrieved via <dependency> in `pom.xml`?

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, I created a blank Maven project, and added to `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0-M3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I then went to Project Settings -> Modules -> + -> Scala, and specified the compiler jar from the drop-down menu as `Maven: org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.11.0-M3`. I receive the error:

```
Compiler library: no scala-library*.jar found
```

Of course, `scala-library-2.11.0-M3.jar` is among the dependencies (transitively), but not stored in the same folder as `scala-compiler-2.11.0-M3.jar`, which is what seems to be confusing the Scala plugin.

Is there any way to use `scala-compiler*.jar` downloaded from a `pom.xml` dependency? Perhaps by manually specifying where to find each JAR?

Before this, I had been using `scala-compiler*.jar` downloaded via Project Settings -> Libraries -> + -> From Maven. This seems to work because IntelliJ sticks all the downloaded JARs in the same folder, which is what the Scala plugin assumes. Simply for aesthetic reasons I would like to know if it can be done with `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the `scala-compiler` as a dependency to be able to build the scala project (neither using maven at command line nor by building from `Build | Make Project` in IntelliJ).

This is a very simple `pom.xml` that I use for scala projects where I don't have scala installed at all and just point IntelliJ to this pom and then I can compile and run any scala code directly from within IntelliJ.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <scala.version>2.10.1</scala.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-make:transitive</arg>
                                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: It appears that yes, it does. Thank you very much, this has solved a lot of problems in my life.

Comment: And it also seems to work for multimodule projects. Thank you!!

Comment: I can't get this to work for IntelliJ 14.  Anyone else have this problem?